# @property NSArray in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, properties, nsarray

I've got a TableviewController with :

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSSArray *myArray;
```

Then I put some objects in my array in the viewdidload

When I click on a row, I want to access to my array in :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But I can't, xcode return NULL every time...

What is the solution ?

Comment: Good question, but could you post the file where you, say, initialize the table view?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. When you hit it, type `po (NSArray*)[self myArray]` and see what you get. If it's nil, you're not creating or assigning an array to your `myArray` property correctly.

Comment: Why weak and not strong? Post the code for your array initialization.

Comment: @Caleb sorry for the totally unrelated question but, how does that work? you can add a breakpoint and change values or use commands or what? Id like to know how that method for checking for stuff works. thanks

Comment: @LuisOscar That's far too big a topic to explain here, but you can read [Debugging and Analyzing Your Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html) in the [Xcode 4 User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...  It sounds like your program is using [automatic reference counting (ARC)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226), where your properties and variables can be weak or strong references, and the retains and releases are generated for you automatically.

From that document:

```
// The following declaration is a synonym for: @property(retain) MyClass *myObject;
@property(strong) MyClass *myObject;

// The following declaration is similar to "@property(assign) MyClass *myObject;"
// except that if the MyClass instance is deallocated,
// the property value is set to nil instead of remaining as a dangling pointer.
@property(weak) MyClass *myObject;
```

ARC isn't generating any retains for your variable myArray, so when you don't have any strong references to it, it's memory is freed and any references to it are nulled, resulting in the behavior you are seeing.  Try changing your property from a weak to a strong reference.  Weak references can be useful for preventing reference cycles and similar situations, but for the usual case where one object "owns" another, and wants it kept alive while the owning object is alive (such as the data in an NSArray used by your TableViewController), you want a strong reference, just as you would have wanted to retain the object if using non-ARC code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it may have to do with the fact that you've declared the `myArray` property as weak, meaning that the setter won't send it a `retain` message. However, I'm there's also the possibility that you're not setting it at all - this occurs to me because, if you did set `myArray`, and the underlying `NSArray` did indeed get released, then it's more likely that `myArray` would be some dangling, invalid reference rather than `nil`.

Where do you set `myArray`? Please post the code!

Comment: I set myArray in the viewdidload and when I change weak for strong everything is ok. Thanks guys you rock !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you need to do this:

```
@interface YourTableView:UITableViewController
 {
         NSArray *_myArray;
 }

@property(non atomic,strong) NSArray *myArray;
```

Now in implementation ;

```
@synthisize myArray=_myArray;
```

I hope this will help you